# quote "*/" when part of pattern matching

Tags: javascript, regex, comments

have code

```
obj.property.style.split( /\s*;\s*/ ).forEach( function(s) {...
```

the problem is that the `*/` in the pattern is serving as a comment delimiter.

for example

```
/* comment this out please
obj.property.style.split( /\s*;\s*/ ).forEach( function(s) {..
OOPS - NOT commented out */
```

what's the customary way to quote this in `regexp`?

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer - good idea, but wish to comment blocks of code, not lines of code

Comment: You could replace `\s*/` with `\s{0,}/`.

Comment: @Blender - `{0,}` - that should work well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `*` qualifier is a shortcut for `{0,}`<sup>1</sup> so:

```
/\s*;\s{0,}/
```

However, as this makes it slightly less-than-usual, I'd really consider just not commenting out the code with `/* .. */` comments.

---

<sup>1</sup> [`{n,}` is specified in ECMAScript 5th Edition](http://es5.github.com/x15.10.html#x15.10.2.7). However, [MDC only lists `{n,m}`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Comment: thanks.  agree on the `/*..*/` comments, but chasing down a missing `}` in a longish piece of code

Comment: @ccyoung Perhaps the block-indent mode of the editor can be changed? (You *are* use a suitable editor, right? Such an editor should also do indenting and perhaps syntax highlighting and parenthesis matching and .. but to find a missing `}`, also consider [jslint](http://www.jslint.com/) :D)

Comment: @ccyoung just to add, there are IDEs that comment entire blocks with `//` instead of `/**/`

Comment: Ok, now **I** understood the question.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your code looks like this:

```
obj.property.style.split( /\s*;\s*/ ).forEach(function(s) {
  ...very...
  ...long...
  ...implementation...
});
```

Taking it from another perspective, rather than block commenting the entire block, why not extract the callback as a standalone function. That way, you only need one line for `forEach()` wherein you can safely line-comment it.

```
function eachHandler(s) {
  ...very...
  ...long...
  ...implementation...
}

//you just prevented the forEach!
//obj.property.style.split( /\s*;\s*/ ).forEach(eachHandler);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [specs](http://es5.github.com/#x7.8.5):

> To specify an empty regular expression, use: `/(?:)/`

In your case: `/\s*;\s*(?:)/`

The `?:` prevents the parens from capturing. If you don't care about captures, you might as well use `/\s*;\s*()/`